# Mongoose: How to find by multiple fields from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongoose

Say I have a Model that looks like this:

```
{ name: String, category: String }
```

And I got an Array with objects like this:

```
var array = [{
    { name: "a", category: "A" }
  , { name: "b, category: "A" }
  , { name: "b", category: "B" }
}]
```

Now I want to find all objects that matches the value pairs in the array. If it was an array of Strings only, the code would be something like `Model.find({ name: {$in: array } })`, but I need something like

```
Model.find({ name,category: {$in: array} })
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could directly use that array in an [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) query to look for docs that match any of those pairs:

```js
var array = [
    { name: "a", category: "A" }
  , { name: "b", category: "A" }
  , { name: "b", category: "B" }
];

Model.find({$or: array}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: or using mongoose's `.or` helper - `Model.find().or(array)`

Comment: How did I not think of that? Thank you so much!